# appendchild meta tag into head tag

Tags: jquery

I try to append the meta tag into the head tags but it won't add into the header. I don't know what was wrong. Here's my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var link = document.createElement('meta');
  link.setAttribute('property', 'og:url');
  link.content = "website/<%=found.category%>/<%=found.slug%>";
  console.log(link)
  // document.head.appendChild(link);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].append(link);
});
</script>'''
```

and this the output of my header

```
<head>
  <title>xxx</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/ChoQPMO.png">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.12.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var link = document.createElement('meta');
  link.setAttribute('property', 'og:url');
  link.content = "website/<%=found.category%>/<%=found.slug%>";
  console.log(link)
  // document.head.appendChild(link);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].append(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
content
```

Comment: Can't reproduce - run the snippet and Inspect it, it looks to be added to the `<head>` as desired

Comment: What do you mean by "*output of my header*"? How did you confirm that it is not added as expected?

Comment: I tried to use `ctrl + u` to view the source and found out is not there. the output of my header is from the view source using `ctrl + u`

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. console head content console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML);

Comment: Viewing the source will only show the original content of the response. If you want to examine what the DOM looks like after the Javascript has run, you'll have to Inspect the page

Comment: but how can I check if the code is succeeded?